# Pass string as variable name to for loop with nunjucks

Tags: for-loop, nunjucks

I have different sites, with different sitenames and try to get the right array on each site. So basically I want to pass the variable name dynamically to the for loop.

```
{% set sitename = "user" %}
{% set blockRef = sitename + 'Blocks' %} //result should be userBlocks

{% set userBlocks = [ 'chats', 'profile', 'settings' ] %}
{% set adminBlocks = [ 'chats', 'archive', 'profile', 'settings' ] %}


{% for blockName in blockRef %}

  //user values from userBlocks array here

{% endfor %}
```

However, the passed name is interpreted as text and does not refer to the given array. Is there a way to make my code dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% set sitename = "user" %}
{% set userBlocks = [ 'chats', 'profile', 'settings' ] %}
{% set adminBlocks = [ 'chats', 'archive', 'profile', 'settings' ] %}
{% set blocks = userBlocks if sitename == 'user' else adminBlocks %}

{% for blockName in blocks %}
  //user values from userBlocks array here
{% endfor %}
```